# C++::GET & SET in a header file

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the `get()` inside a header file of C++:

For example: this is the file: test.hpp

```
class A {
public:
A(std::string f, int id):file(f), index(id){};

std::string getFile(){return file;};
int getIndex(){return id;};

private:
  std::string file;
  int index;
};
}
```

But then I get a problem:

> undefined reference to 'vtable A'.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Please post the exact code you’re using. The above code (apart from a redundant closing brace) should work, and it certainly won’t give you the error you’re seeing.

Comment: Well, except that he's returning _id_, when his class contains a member called _index_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int getIndex(){return id;};
```

There is no member named 'id', so this line should be

```
int getIndex(){return index;};
```

Then you have a closen brace too much. Also note that there is no need for a semicolon after the curly braces. In addition, class members which do not modify the object should always be declared as const, it helps enormously in keeping a consistent concept about what should do modifications and what shouldn't.

This is how it would finally look:

```
#include <string>

class A {
public:
A(std::string f, int id):file(f), index(id){}

std::string getFile() const {return file;}
int getIndex() const {return index;}

private:
  std::string file;
  int index;
};
```

Comment: This however, doesn't answer how the compiler would output an error about a missing vtable, but the original code doesn't have anything inside that could produce this.

Comment: and don't forget to add the consts

Comment: You're right, getFile and getIndex should be const, added this.